# Using inner .Any() is it the same as doing two seperate checks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application . and i have the following 2 model classes :-

```
public class ScanInfo
    {
        public TSServer TSServer { set; get; }
        public Resource Resource { set; get; }
        public List<ScanInfoVM> VMList { set; get; }
    }
public class ScanInfoVM
    {
        public TSVirtualMachine TSVM { set; get; }
        public Resource Resource { set; get; }
    }
```

now will these two operation be the same :-

Operation1

```
var vmlist = scaninfo.SelectMany(a => a.VMList).ToList();
if (vmlist.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower()))
```

Operation2

```
 if (scaninfo.Any(a=>a.VMList.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower())))
```

or they will be executed differently ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest way to answer your question authoritatively is to profile the actual generated SQL: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof or MS SQL Profiler will do the trick.

Comment: @ToddSprang an easier method http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpeder/archive/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option has an expensive operation that is flattening the list elements using `SelectMany`.

Other than that, both should work same, ie. break at finding first match.

**In case of Database**

In case of this query getting executed on the database, the first option is bad, since it will bring all the data to the application memory *(since you are using `ToList`)* and later it will perform the `Any` check on in memory object.

The second one will execute the query at the database end and only returns the result to application. It will not bring the data back to application.

Comment: now these lists contain data that comes from calling an API , so the data is not retrieved from the DB or executed there,, all the operation are done at the memory ..

Comment: Even in the case of an IEnumerable, the entire Enumerable will be iterated over (because of the ToList) vs breaking at first match.

Answer (score 2):

No, they will be executed differently.

The first one is much worse.  It causes scaninfo to be enumerated and then put all the ScanInfoVMs into a list, and then it is filtering the ScanInfoVMs using `Any`.

The second one is much better, but it is checking if any `ScanInfo`s exists that have a ScanInfoVM that match your criteria.

In short, they execute differently and check slightly different things, but since you are only caring if any exist, then they should give the same result, but the second one will execute MUCH faster, returning only a single boolean from the database and it will stop looking after it finds the first, while your first returned everything from the database and then started checking.

If you simply remove the `ToList()` in the first operation then which performs better is something you would need to run a profiler to determine.  I suspect that they would execute the same way, but that is determined by how the database provider translates the expression tree into SQL and how the SQL server optimizes the resultant query.

Answer (score 2):

```
var vmlist = scaninfo.SelectMany(a => a.VMList).ToList();
```

This runs a SQL query along to obtain each `VMList` row associated with an `ScanInfo` row, builds a `VMList` object for each, and then creates a list in memory to store them all.

```
if (vmlist.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower()))
```

This will run through that list, and for each item work out if `Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower()` is true (not memoising the value of `vmname.ToLower()`) and return true as soon as it finds a match, or false if it never finds one.

```
if (scaninfo.Any(a=>a.VMList.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower())))
```

This will run an `EXISTS` SQL query on the database and return `true` or `false` accordingly.

We would generally expect this to be much faster, and certainly to use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for Enumerable.cs, Any is defined as:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and Select and its call to SelectIterator are:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (selector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
    return SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}

 static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
    int index = -1;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        checked { index++; }
        yield return selector(element, index);
    }
}
```

So they will execute differently, but from looking at your LINQ expressions they will *evaluate* the same.

HTH

Comment: so you mean they will internally be executed in different way ,, but will give exactly the same result ?

Comment: Yes, they will execute differently but give you the same result.

Furthermore, I agree with @Habib response, of the two use the Any.Any version (option 2).  Option 1 creates a new list that you don't need (or returns all records from DB).